# Jquery code not working on specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, prestashop

I am using Advanced Top Menu in one of my websites: www.vente2site.fr
I needed to add a count of the number of ads to the links in my menu.
So i did not have any other option except jquery.

On my homepage: https://www.vente2site.fr/ - the count is working perfectly, it is the case for all pages except:

https://www.vente2site.fr/e-commerces-sites-marchands-en-vente-a-ceder/2064-pret-a-porter-feminin-et-accessoires-de-modemod-elles.html - i have put conditions to prevent the code from running on this page because it was causing a 302 redirect.

It the product page (prestashop 1.4.8) that is used as the page for showing an ad.

Below is the code i am using:

```
function replacetext(url, inittext, text, value) {
        var foundin = $('.adtm_elements_5 *:contains("' + text + '")');
        //foundin.html("<table><tr><td style='vertical-align:middle'>" + inittext + </a></td></tr></table>");
        foundin.html("<a href='" + url + "'>" + inittext + " ( <b style='color:#01b196;padding:0px!important;font-weight:bold;margin:0px!important;'>" + value + "</b> )</a>");
        return false;
}

function replacetextDataroom(url, inittext, text, value) {
        var foundin = $('.adtm_elements_11 *:contains("' + text + '")');
        //foundin.html("<table><tr><td style='vertical-align:middle'>" + inittext + </a></td></tr></table>");
        foundin.html("<a href='" + url + "'>" + inittext + " ( <b style='color:#01b196;padding:0px!important;font-weight:bold;margin:0px!important;'>" + value + "</b> )</a>");
        return false;
}

function replacecount(url, inittext, text, id) {
        var vars = new Object();
        vars['cat'] = id;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getComptage.php",
            data: vars,
            success: function (msg) {
                replacetext(url, inittext, text, msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
}

function getdataroom(url, inittext, text, id) {
        var vars = new Object();
        vars['idc'] = id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getDataroomAccessCount.php",
            data: vars,
            success: function (msg) {
                replacetextDataroom(url, inittext, text, msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("e-commerces-sites-marchands-en-vente-a-ceder") > -1 || 
   window.location.href.indexOf("sites-internet-e-business-en-vente") > -1 || 
   window.location.href.indexOf("medias-digitaux") > -1 || 
   window.location.href.indexOf("saas") > -1 ||  
   window.location.href.indexOf("applications-ios-android-fb-en-vente") > -1){

}else{
        replacecount('https://www.vente2site.fr/5-e-commerces-sites-marchands-en-vente-a-ceder','Sites Marchands','(CCC1)', 5);
        replacecount('https://www.vente2site.fr/6-sites-internet-e-business-en-vente','Services en ligne','(CCC2)', 6);
        replacecount('https://www.vente2site.fr/172-medias-digitaux','Médias digitaux','(CCC3)', 172);
        replacecount('https://www.vente2site.fr/173-saas','SaaS','(CCC4)', 173);
        replacecount('https://www.vente2site.fr/7-applications-ios-android-fb-en-vente','Apps Mobiles','(CCC5)', 7);

        getdataroom('https://www.vente2site.fr/repreneurdataroom.php?opp=view','Datarooms auquelles jai acces','(CCC6)', {$idclient});
 }
```

This code is called in the footer of my website.

Comment: Hi, can you further elaborate on the problem and where we can see it on the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify absolute path to the php files instead of relative path. You can do that by adding a slash `/` at the start of the URL you're making the request to. This is because those php files are located in the root of your domain.

So you need to change your functions to be like this:

```
function replacecount(url, inittext, text, id) {
        var vars = new Object();
        vars['cat'] = id;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/getComptage.php",
            data: vars,
            success: function (msg) {
                replacetext(url, inittext, text, msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

 function getdataroom(url, inittext, text, id) {
        var vars = new Object();
        vars['idc'] = id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/getDataroomAccessCount.php",
            data: vars,
            success: function (msg) {
                replacetextDataroom(url, inittext, text, msg);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you forgot the "/" in your answer, but it was the solution to my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: Woops, I was sure I edited the answer and added the slash. Now it's fixed.